# How many permutations are there from x bits to y bits?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations

Can you have a permutation function where the size of the domain isn't the size of the range?

I know the number of permutations from x bits to x bits is $2^x!$, but if you can permute x bits to y bits, how many permutations are there?

Comment: The number of permutations of $x$ bits is $x!$, not $2^x!$, which is a *much* larger number (at least if $x$ is of "reasonable" size).  For example, $5!=120, 2^5!=263130836933693530167218012160000000$

Comment: @RossMillikan No, he is correct, because an $x$-bit permutation has space $[0, 2^x)$. Otherwise symmetric cryptography would be horribly broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a permutation of a set, by definition, is a *bijection*: a one-to-one (injective) and "onto" (surjective) function from the set to itself.

Hence, strictly speaking, no. If the size of the domain $D$ is $x$ and the size of the range $R$ is $y$, and $\;x\neq y,\;$ then there *cannot* be a bijection (hence there is ***no*** permutation) from from $D \to R$, nor from $R \to D.$

Comment: Well said.  There can be functions from $D \to R$ but not permutations.

Comment: Thanks, @Ross: I'm glad you commented on the correct number of permutations of x bits! Clearly, I failed to do so!

Comment: Again permutation. +